# I wanto copy text in tag in list

Tags: javascript, django

Step 1
get id form button

Step 2
copy text in td for same id

Codepen)
https://codepen.io/terecal/pen/LoxmbP?editors=1010

```js
    $(".copy_code").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = this.id
        alert("id : ", id)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>code</td>
  <td colspan="122" id="my_code_122"> hello world </td>
  </tr>  
</table>
<button type="button" name="button" id="122" class="copy_code">copy</button>
```

Is it possible?

p.s

I applied your method.

The following code works fine

`

```
    $(".copy_code").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        alert("id : " + id)

        var text = document.getElementById(id),
        textVal = text.innerText;
        textTd = $(`#my_code_${id}`).text()

        alert("copy code " + textTd) // textVal  code copy

        // I want to copy this text as if pressing ctrl + c. Is there a way? Thank you if you let me know.
    });
```

`

The problem is almost solved.

I just want to copy the text I got as if I pressed ctrl + C

Can you tell me how?

ps2

current code is this

```
    $(".copy_code").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
        alert("id : " + id)

        var text = document.getElementById(id),
        textVal = text.innerText;
        textTd = $(`#my_code_${id}`).text()

        alert("copy code " + textTd) // textVal  code copy
        // I want to copy this text as if pressing ctrl + c. Is there a way? Thank you if you let me know.

        var dummy = document.createElement('textarea');
        dummy.value = textTd;
        //
        document.body.appendChild(dummy );
        dummy.select();
        //
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(dummy);

        alert("copy code2 " + textTd)
    });
```

and copy is normally works

but after ctrl + v

it's new line(br) is not work  ^^;;

```
original:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name= 'css_challenge'
urlpatterns = [

]

copy:
 from django.contrib import adminfrom django.urls import path, includefrom . import views

app_name= 'css_challenge'urlpatterns = [

]
```

is it possible to apply new line??

Comment: Swelcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately it ain't too clear what you're asking. What is the meaning of my_code_{{comment.id}}?

Comment: it's django's template syntex and i changed this to 122 for properly ex code thanks~!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
$(".copy_code").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id)

        // var copyText = document.getElementById("my_code");
        // copyText.select();
        // document.execCommand("copy");
        // alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);

    });
```

Comment: I thought it would be, but it does not work.
It does not work on code pens.

Comment: coma in alert was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this. First of all you need to put a + rather than a , in your alert. Secondly, I don't know if you specifically need copy functionality because you want to paste the text somewhere else. AFAIK, I've only "copied" like that on inputs/textareas. I am unsure whether other elements support that type of API. Regardless, the below code should grab the text content. I haven't tested it but there ya go.

```
$(".copy_code").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = this.id
        alert("id : "+ id)

        var text = document.getElementById(id),
            textVal = text.innerText;

        console.log(textVal);
    });
```

Comment: $(".copy_code").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id')
       let tdtext=$(`#my_code_${id}`).text()
       
      console.log( tdtext) // get the text of the particular td

    });

Comment: it's work and i sloved probelm but i want copy like ctrl + c for text I got could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't sure. I'm glad you were able to figure it out below!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy text to the clipboard using javascript - it's just a little inconvenient. The text has to be part of a html element.

Let's start by creating a dummy text element

```
var dummy = document.createElement('textarea');
```

and give it the value of your variable

```
dummy.value = textTd;
```

add the dummy to the DOM

```
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

select it

```
dummy.select();
```

finally copy it's text content to the system clipboard

```
document.execCommand('copy');
```

and ultimately remove the created element from the DOM again

```
document.body.removeChild(dummy);
```